# Why I am not getting the POST data of image?

Tags: php

My index.html file:

```
    <form action="upload.php" method="post">
    Title: <input type="text" name="title" required="required"></br>
    Filename: <input type="file" name="file"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="upload" class="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>
```

And upload.php:

> ```
> if (isset($_POST["upload"])){
>     upload();
> }
> ```

Well, I have a function that uploads and there is no problem, in that function I think. Help me plzz

Comment: What does `upload` function contains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because the form does not encrypt your file. Just use this:

```
 <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

instead of

```
 <form action="upload.php" method="post">
```

in the 1st line of form

Comment: And additionlly, if you are using if for image only, its safer to use Image BArrier in your upload function: Eg:
       `if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif"))){ //Bla //Bla}`

Comment: Should I really do that? Necessary? And Thank you again @Tika

Comment: Yeah! You shuould make a barrier. If you let to upload alll files, your site will be venerauble. Take an example, if you let them upload PHP files, they can even delete and overrite your files on the server

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `enctype= "multipart/form-data"` to send files through form

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype= "multipart/form-data">
```

`enctype='multipart/form-data'` is an encoding type that allows files to be sent through a POST. Quite simply, without this encoding the files cannot be sent through POST.

Answer (score 1):

For file uploading in form you have to add `enctype= "multipart/form-data"` in form. It sends form-data encoded as "multipart/form-data".

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype= "multipart/form-data">
```